# Fetching and Posting data to a rest microservice

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am trying to implement HTTP services GET and POST with my Rest micro service created.

I am able to fetch data from my Rest micro service.

But I am unable make a POST request.

Below shown is my code for Rest micro service

**WebController.java**

```
package com.central.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import com.central.model.Users;
import com.central.repository.UsersRepository;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@RestController
public class WebController {
    private static final String NULL = null;
    @Autowired
    UsersRepository userRepo;

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    @RequestMapping("/checkUsers")
    public String checkLogin() throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<Users> useObj = (List<Users>) userRepo.findAll();
        return (mapper.writeValueAsString(useObj));
    }

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/checkByCredential", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String checkLoginByName(@RequestBody Users user) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Users useObj1 = userRepo.findByUsernameAndPassword(user.username, user.password);
        return (mapper.writeValueAsString(useObj1));
    }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BasicService } from './basic.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations  : [ AppComponent],
  imports       : [BrowserModule,HttpModule,FormsModule ],
  providers     : [BasicService],
  bootstrap     : [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BasicService } from './basic.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
                <div style="margin-left:50px; height: 200px; overflow: auto;"> 
                 <table>
                     <tr><td>Username</td>&emsp;&emsp;<td>Password</td></tr>
                     <tr *ngFor= " let item of data">
                 <td>{{ item.username }}</td>&emsp;&emsp;<td>{{ item.password }}</td>
                 </tr>
                 </table>
                </div>


      <h2>Login</h2>
        <form role="form">
          <div ng-control-group="credentials">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              #username
              id="username"
              ng-control="username"
              required>

            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input
              type="password"
              #password
              id="password"
              ng-control="password"
              required>
          </div>
          <button (click)="checkByCredential(username,password)">Login</button>
        </form>`
})


export class AppComponent {
  title: string;
  data: any;

  constructor(private MyService: BasicService) {
    this.title = "Angular Service";

    this.MyService.GetUsers()
      .subscribe(users => { this.data = users });
  }

  checkByCredential(username: string, password: string) {
    this.MyService.checkByCredential(username, password).subscribe(users => { this.data = users });
  }
}
```

**basic.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class BasicService {
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  GetUsers() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/checkUsers')
      .map(result => result.json());
  }

  checkByCredential(username: string, password: string) {
    const user = { username: username, password: password };
    return this.http
      .post('http://localhost:8080/checkByCredential', user)
      .map(result => result.json());
  }
}
```

And when I am submitting data via my form I am getting this error in my console as shown below in the images

[image]

[image]

But with my Postman when I am trying to make Post request with username and password ,I am able to get back the data as shown below in the images

[image]

[image]

can any body please help me out to resolve the Post request in angular 2

updated screen shots after updation in my framework
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you check the request parameters in postman and compare it with your post request from Angular application

Comment: Indeed, there must be a difference in request parameters, considering that Spring is returning a **400** (bad request). Also check the logs of your Spring boot application and the full response of the call in your browser, usually that gives a good indication about what's wrong.

Comment: thank you  so much for your response ..ok i will try to do this

Comment: This error is generated by your framework... you should first check the network tab on chrome and inspect your request body to make sure it matches what you expect it to. Based on the code in your service, I imagine it will. Next, you see in your console, your server is actually giving you an error message, you should expand it so that we can see what it is.

Comment: ok i will edit my question

Comment: your service was fine, but the erorr was actually in your component template, answered.

Comment: please view the scree shots i edited after updation .please suggest me a solution

Comment: I did, however your screen shots show you're now getting a 200 response from your web server, so the original question is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a 400 from your service because you aren't acually sending a value to your server.

this line:

```
<button (click)="checkByCredential(username,password)">Login</button>
```

is the problematic one.  Those 2 variables are template variable, which refer to the actual input element, not the value of the input element, so you need to do this:

```
<button (click)="checkByCredential(username.value,password.value)">Login</button>
```

and this should work at that point. Though I'd recommend switching to reactive forms or ngModel as a longer term solution.

As for debugging this, using console.log, the network tab on chrome, and in this case, even the error message generated by your server framework all would've shown you exactly what was going wrong right away.

Something like this:

```
checkByCredential(username: string, password: string) {
    console.log(username, password);
    this.MyService.checkByCredential(username, password).subscribe(users => { this.data = users });
}
```

would've immediately told you that you weren't getting the expected value.

As well, on the network tab in chrome, you can view the actual request body you're sending and make sure it isn't getting malformed.

Finally, if you look closely at the 400 error you're getting back (btw, 400 always means bad user input), it has a specific error message that probably gives you a clue as to what's going on.

Your secondary error is because you're trying to use ngFor to iterate an object, which is not allowed, you can only use ngFor with arrays.  Your real problem is that this is poorly designed and you try to show a master list and a single detail item in the same element.  You should redesign your page so that your "checked user" and your "user list" are different display elements.  But for testing, you can log to the console like this:

```
this.MyService.checkByCredential(username, password).subscribe(users => console.log(users));
```

Comment: but now i am getting this error "AppComponent.html:5 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed"

Comment: you're getting that error because you're trying to ngFor over "data" and data is an object, you can only use ngFor with arrays. You can either make it an array or not use ngFor.

Comment: but that i am doing it to fetch the data i.e username and password , just putting in the template for the view

Comment: ngFor is for ITERATING ARRAYS in template, the data you're trying to display is NOT AN ARRAY.

Comment: so how can do it without ngFor?

Comment: but using this code snippet iam unable to fetch data  from my micro service 
  <tr *ngIf= "data">
    <td>{{ data.username }}</td>&emsp;&emsp;<td>{{ data.password }}</td>
</tr>

Comment: Your response log clearly shows a 200 response, so you are fetching the data, the problem is that you don't know the difference between binding array data and single object data to a template.

Comment: I can't because I don't know your desired behavior.  When the server checks a user successfully, what should happen? Should the entire list of users be replaced? should the checked user be added to the list again? should the checked user be high lighted? I don't know.  You need to decide as an application designer and implement that behavior. I changed my answer to reflect a solution.

Comment: when the server checks a user successfully .it should provide me the entered credential i.e username and password in my console

Comment: thank you so much for your co operation ... i am sooo happy ..thanks a lot

Comment: Yes. Thank you for your response and guidance.Once again thank you for your valuable time.

Comment: can i follow you

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. The problem is caused by Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS). I created a proxy file to redirect traffic from `localhost:4200` to my spring localhost (in your case it's `localhost:8080`).

In your case I recommend to create a `proxy.conf.json` file like this:

```
{
  "/": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

.. and change the absolute paths in your code to relative paths e.g.

```
return this.http
   .post('http://localhost:8080/checkByCredential', user) 
   .map(result => result.json()
)}
```

to:

```
return this.http
   .post('/checkByCredential', user) 
   .map(result => result.json()
)}
```

You can run your angular application (proxy enabled) with the following command:

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

Your project structure lookes like:

[image: Project structure]

---

Your WebController is also too complicated; you are serializing to JSON, but that is not necessary.

```
package com.central.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import com.central.model.Users;
import com.central.repository.UsersRepository;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

    @RestController
    public class WebController {
        private static final String NULL = null;
        @Autowired
        UsersRepository userRepo;

        @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
        @GetMapping("/checkUsers")
        public List<Users> checkLogin() {
            return userRepo.findAll();
        }

        @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
        @PostMapping(value = "/checkByCredential")
        public Users checkLoginByName(@RequestBody Users user) throws Exception {
            return userRepo.findByUsernameAndPassword(user.username, user.password);
        }
    }
```

I think something goes wrong with parsing from/to JSON.

Don't forget to remove the mapping methods! For example, change this

```
return this.http
   .post('http://localhost:8080/checkByCredential', user) 
   .map(result => result.json()
)}
```

to:

```
return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/checkByCredential', user)
```

Comment: thank you so much for your response ..i will try this out

Comment: "Proxy config file C:\Angular\httprest\proxy.conf.json does not exist."

Comment: You need to create the `proxy.conf.json` in the root dir

Comment: @Heena No, not `src` but alongside the `package.json` file

Comment: i tried creating it in app folder but the same error

Comment: Check my answer, you need to create it in the same dir as `package.json`

Comment: yes now i created it along side of package.json ,but still i am ending up with the same error as earlier i mentioned in my question as "zone.js:2933 POST http://localhost:4200/checkByCredential 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: yes my project structure is same as you have mentioned

Comment: yes i enabled cors in my micro service. please get me a solution for this

Comment: Check my answer again

Comment: they're using the http service, the response has to be parsed to json, but regardless, that happens after the response is received, and the response if a 400, this error is occurring either in the request or on the server, this is all wrong.

Comment: @bryan60 you're right, I updated my answer with a JSON response in Spring

Comment: i see the actual issue, they're not actually sending any values to the server.

Comment: I'm sorry but this entire answer is wrong, setting up a proxy conf won't solve any CORS issues in a production environment, and this code never even had a CORS problem in the first place, the web controller was clearly fine since postman was working, and .json() absolutely must be called on the response.

Comment: @bryan60 In prod you are running the api and frontend mostly on the same domain, so you don't have the CORS problem in prod

Comment: that is also wrong... More often than not the API and front end run on separate sub domains of the same root domain because distributing static files is a waste of API resources. The correct solution to a CORS issue is to set up your server to add CORS headers, not using a proxy conf. which again, was already done correctly here.